# Where to store social network photos and videos?

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, cloud-storage, video-hosting, storage

I have a social network with 100,000 users. I allow users to upload photos and videos now I feel like it is becoming too much for my dedicated server. Should I get another dedicated server? A content delivery network? A cloud storage like amazon ec2? Please help me as I am really confused on this one. I am mainly a programmer and not an expert on these decisions.

Comment: Get an expert! Always the best solution.

Comment: How can you get to 100k users and not have a clue how to scale your infrastructure?

Comment: @MDMarra Facebook-Killer!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, remove it from the web server and store it on another device. Store it on a [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) volume and utilize its deduplication features so that you're not using up expensive storage and you also have a robust, error resistant filesystem.

Yes, you can use Amazon / cloud storage. Nothing "wrong" with that, but there is an expense to that solution that will become more expensive than doing it yourself at a certain point. Where is that point? You have to graph and monitor use over time to figure out your sweet spot. You are graphing and monitoring all of your usage metrics, right?

How do you do this whole project? You seriously need to hire a professional systems administrator / engineer to design and implement this. Do your users a favor and don't risk their data.

Comment: Yup - Hire or contract a sysadmin/architect, or be prepared to become one.